# Why is my ionic www folder not being tracked by Git?

Tags: angularjs, linux, git, ionic-framework, bitbucket

I am creating an app with Ionic Framework & AngularJS. I am also tracking the project with git locally as well as remotely on bitbucket.

**My setup:**

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS: Distributor ID: LinuxMint Description:  Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca 
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

I have noticed that though my commits are being tracked, everything in my www folder isn't. On bitbucket I get this strange look:

[image: screenshot from bitbucket showing www folder cannot be browsed & isn't being tracked]

I have tried deleting the repository both on bitbucket and locally and starting again but still www isn't being tracked. As you can see on the timestamps on the commits this has been bothering me for over a month now. Please help!

Comment: dont see `www` folder timestamp as it was only uploaded for first time repository.check files timestamp under www folder

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad no the time stamp is not the point of the question. Point of the question is how can I get www to be tracked together with the other files. Its not being tracked currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www` is either a nested git repo whose **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** [SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) is recorded, or a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
(most likely the former, since there is no `.gitmodules`)

If you want to get rid of it, you must do:

```
git rm www # no trailing slash
git add .
git commit -m "remove www"
git push
```

Then you can copy back `www` content and add/track it normally.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I on doing $git push I get back the message that, "Everything up-to-date", but when I check my remote repo it has not updated anything

Comment: @user3086325 Does your local `git log` shows a new commit "remove www"?

Comment: @user3086325 what git branch returns? Or git status? Are you on an active branch (one with a '*' in front of it) What version of Git are you using?

Comment: I only have one branch, master and yes its the active one. git version 1.9.1

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: @user3086325 Then the remote should reflect the same commits... What `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: $ git remote -v
origin git@bitbucket.org:masta_coda/churchify.git (fetch)
origin git@bitbucket.org:masta_coda/churchify.git (push)

Comment: tried the original instructions gain and they worked. Thanks